# GUI API for directX?

Tags: user-interface, api, directx

Is there any GUI API that can be used together with DirectX other than MFC, WIN32, Winforms
and WPF?

Comment: You can use any win32 window as surface. so i think ports such as QT, GTK will work too.

Comment: Tough I think QT is a pretty interesting API, the documentation related to DirectX Interoperability is scarce if not inexistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing your own DirectX rendering, you can use any GUI technology for windows that exposes an HWND.

Just use the "panel" equivelent in whatever toolkit you want, and feed it's handle (HWND) into DirectX to initialize the device.  This technique is the same, no matter whether you use MFC, Windows Forms, WPF, Qt, GTK, FLTK, or any other framework.

As long as you can get a handle to the window, you can do it.  It's just easier, and potentially more flexible, with some of the Microsoft toolkits.  (For example, using D3DImage makes it seamless in WPF...)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [CEGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It's pretty popular especially for games. And it supports both Direct3d and OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx). Ultimately WPF or WinForms will be used to get a display surface - can't draw in Windows without a window - but you'll need an additional framework for rendering.

Comment: But XNA does not have a consistent design model for GUI. As fas as I know, I would have to use XNA in winforms or WPF.

Please tell me If I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance.